# go get using ssh instead of https (NOT on github)

Tags: git, go, go-modules

We have a private code repository accessible only through ssh/git (no https), and we would like to host our go code/modules there.

First I tried:

```
git config --global url."git@code.internal.local:".insteadOf "https://code.internal.local/"
```

so, both of the following work just fine:

- `git clone git@code.internal.local:reponame.git`
- `git clone https://code.internal.local/reponame`

But `go get code.internal.local/reponame` fails, as go still insists on trying https://... not git.

```
package code.internal.local/reponame: unrecognized import path "code.internal.local/reponame": https fetch: Get "https://code.internal.local/reponame?go-get=1": dial tcp 192.168.0.5:443: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 11):

I checked my **.gitconfig** and found this (for *github* private repo) -

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

above configuration is working for me. Also you can try creating a **.netrc** file in your project root, but that should **not** be pushed to remote code repo.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in the title: this is not on github. this is not a solution.

Comment: `.netrc` use username and password, in this context, it is SSH. I think you are wrong?

Comment: @SherifEldeeb (or anyone else who is interested): The same configuration works for any other git setups

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

The behaviour you're observing is detailed in the section ["Remote import paths"](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) of the `go get` documentation.
In particular, just by looking at the remote import path `code.internal.local/reponame`, `go get` has no way to know which VCS and at which URL in particular is used to actually *host* that package.

To solve that problem, `go get` employs a set of HTTPS (and HTTP, as a fallback, which has to be explicitly enabled) GET requests to a set of special URLs constructed out of the specified import path.
It is assumed that whatever serves such calls is able to respond with a reply which identifies the VCS to use and the URL of the repository.

#### Possible solutions

If you're using modules, you might set up a dedicated "module proxy" wherever is convenient for your team (also, there may be deployed many proxies) and make the team members use the `GOPROXY` environment variable which points at the convenient instance.  See `go help modules` for more info.

Otherwise, if you can put a webserver to answer remote import path resolution requests, you can do that; nginx and apache can be used for that just with their stock modules.

Otherwise you might need to resort to manual operation.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a detail answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65925691/348719

Basically, you should add `.git` suffix to `require` at client and `module` at server. Without `.git` suffix, `go get` will use https.

- At client (go.mod) (change the version number to correct one):

```
require code.internal.local/reponame.git v0.1.0
```

And it's better add `go env -w GOPRIVATE=code.internal.local`

- At server (go.mod)

```
module code.internal.local/reponame.git
```