# Why does go module ssh custom private repo (non-github) config still request https fetch?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am using Go modules.

In order to use module version, I cannot use local module. For example:

```
replace locakpkg => ../localpkg v0.1.0
```

The above will fail because replacement local path cannot have version so far (go 1.15).

Thus, to make the module version work, I decided to use a private ssh repo.

I did search how to make private ssh repo work for two days.

By following many online articles, I did

```
git config --global url.user@private.com:.insteadOf https://private.com/
go env -w GOPRIVATE=private.com
```

I found out go get will always do https fetch to check ssl credential. So I configured a https server properly too.

But in the end, I still get an error message:

```
unrecognized import path "private.com/foo": reading https://private.com/foo?go-get=1: 404 Not Found
```

I did google this error and found out this spec https://golang.org/ref/mod#vcs-find which says I have to let the server reply with `<meta name="go-import" content="root-path vcs repo-url">` for https fetch request.

- If there is a way to use git tag versioning in local module packages, I am OK to use local replace in go.mod instead of configuring a private ssh repo.
- If the above point is not possible, how to avoid https fetch when I configure a private ssh repo? I think ssh repo has nothing to do with https protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I am using go 1.15 at linux. The latest stable version while posting this answer)

I solved the problem and posting here, hopefully, this will help other people one day. I don't find any correct answer by my search online.

In short, the answer is to use `.git` suffix in all places. Without `.git` suffix, `go mod tidy` and `go get` will use `https` instead of `ssh` (git).

### At Client:

The file `~/.gitconfig` (at linux) if you use `/repopath/foo.git` path at server:

```
[url "ssh://user@private.com"]
    insteadOf = https://private.com
```

The file `~/.gitconfig` (at linux) if you use `~/repopath/foo.git` path at server:

```
[url "user@private.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://private.com/
```

Execute the following to update `~/.config/go/env` at linux:

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=private.com
```

In `go.mod`, it should use

```
require private.com/repopath/foo.git v0.1.0
```

In `file.go`, it should be

```
import private.com/repopath/foo.git
```

### At SSH Server

in `foo.git/go.mod` at private server should have:

```
module private.com/repopath/foo.git
```

And make sure the git repo at server has tag version `v0.1.0`. Don't forget to use `git push --tags` at client to update the tag version to the server. Without `--tags`, tag version will not be pushed.

After adding `.git` suffix to all the required places, `go mod tidy` and `go get` will no longer send https request.